# Select Object from Object' s list using lambda expression

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8

I have a `List<User>` and I want add a method that return a particular User found using Id. I want make that using lambda expression so I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
...
List<User> user = users.stream().filter(x -> x.id == id).collect(Collectors.toList());
return user[0];
```

This code dosen't compile and give me these errors:

```
The method stream() is undefined for the type List<User>
Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above *
Collectors cannot be resolved
```

- I'm using eclipse 4.4.3 Kepler and I have installed java 8 in the machine and the plugin for working with java8 in eclipse.

Comment: check compliance level.. Goto project>properties>Java Compiler. Set compliance level to 1.8

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Advice: If you want just first element matchig a condition, don't collect all elements to list (it's a bit overkill), use `findFirst()` method instead:

```
return users.stream().filter(x -> x.id == id).findFirst().get();
```

Note that `findFirst()` will return an [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) object, and `get()` will throw an exception if there is no such element.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems.

- You have to enable Java 1.8. Compliance Level in Eclipse and successfully import the Java8 specific classes/interfaces. What you have to do is the following:

  1. Right-click on the project and select `Properties`
  2. Select `Java Compiler` in the window that has been opened
  3. Under `JDK Compliance` unselect the `Use compliance level from execution environment....` checkbox and then select `1.8` from the `Compliance level` dropdown.
  4. Click `OK` and your done.

After you do that, you will notice that the `return` statement is not compiling. This is because the `List` object in Java is not an array, and therefore statements like `user[0]` are invalid for lists. What you have to do is:

```
return user.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 Stream API to return a particular User found by Id in a list. Take a look at this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java#5-java-8-stream-api).

```
User user = users.stream()
  .filter(x -> x.id == id)
  .findAny()
  .orElse(null);
```

- Invoke stream() on the list
- Call the filter() method with a proper Predicate
- Call the findAny() construct, which returns **the first element that matches the filter predicate wrapped in an Optional** if such an element exists

For convenience, we default to null in case an Optional is empty, but this might not always be the best choice for every scenario.